# Not sure which site to post my vague programming question

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm interested in coding a website with a certain set of functions and since I have no idea on how to approach the problem, and what technologies to begin coding with, I'd like some advice. I've seen somewhat similar questions asked on SO but they've been shot down by mods saying that it's `'not a proper question.'`

So I was wondering, where is the proper place to ask a somewhat vague question of this sort? (I was thinking WebApplications.)

Thanks!

**Edit**: So it seems META needs to come up with something to fix this flaw..

**Edit 2** : Or not.

Comment: there's no good place for these. Who do you think would like to answer them?

Comment: Web Apps is for **users** of web applications not writers, so even if it wasn't vague it would be off topic there.

Comment: Application designers/Software Devs will be able to answer my questions. (Thousands on SO)

Comment: And each one would have their own opinion.  This is known as a bikeshed question--as in, "dear cycling experts, what color should I paint my bikeshed?" They're somewhat valid, fun to ask, fun to answer, but WE HATE FUN. Also it can be answered hundreds of different ways, all of which are valid.  SE concentrates on answerable questions, not polls or lists of things or discussions.  Narrow scope, and such.

Comment: Why do you hate fun?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ...I have no idea on how to approach the problem, and what technologies to begin coding with...

Stack Exchange has chosen not to support these type of open ended questions.  The main reason is due to the fact that there are a million ways to do something, and everyone has their preferred method for attacking a given project.

Such questions cannot, by definition, have an objectively correct answer.  They invite everyone to contribute their suggested solution.  May solutions will be similar, but still be posted as separate answers.

Unfortunately this is the type of a question which doesn't fit well into Stack Exchange.

You can try the chat rooms, or do more research into the subject, find a few experts, and approach them.  Alternately there are a lot of forums that can help guide you.

This isn't a case of there not being a specific site for your question in the network, but that the network itself doesn't support this type of question on any site.

That being said, if you can narrow your problem down to a series of very specific, answerable questions, you might be able to glean the same knowledge from the community of experts.  It'll take more time and effort on your part, but it can be done and done well.  Be aware that there are question limits (number of questions per day/month) so you'll have to be careful.

Comment: Thanks, you're right!

Comment: And therein lies the key: *effort*.  Put some in, you get some back.

Answer (score 2):

This question is broad. Very broad. Broad enough that parts of it cover different SE sites - UX for how your site should look, SO for how you should program specific parts of your site, CR if you're doing it all by yourself, or PM if you're doing it in a team.

Make a plan, narrow your project down to workable parts, **then** if you have questions for these individual parts, and you've researched on your own and haven't found answers to these questions, you can consider asking the individual SE sites those specific questions.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to follow this.